# What does "pertinent biological information" mean in an essay

Tags: vocabulary

I was asked to write an essay about my career objectives and goals, major interests, exprience or any **pertinent biological information**. I tried to figure the meaning of the last part but with no success

My dictionary shows that pertinent means *relevant* to, so they're asking me to write about biological information related to my career objectives and goals? how can biological information be related to this?

Comment: That is a _weird_ thing to ask for. You're not misunderstanding anything.

Comment: I think it's more likely that they meant *biographical information*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Thanks, that's probably what they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native speaker, I also have no idea what this would mean.

I suspect, as Damkerng wrote in his comment, that either they or you have got the wrong word, and what they were really asking for is pertinent **biographical** information; in other words, something about your life history that is relevant to whatever it is you're applying for. This is a common type of question to encounter on applications for schools or jobs.

Unless there is some missing context--for example, the essay is applying to be in human cloning experiments--"pertinent biological information" is not idiomatic English in this context.